# Javascript: Improve four nested loops?

Tags: javascript

I have a complex array of objects with nested arrays.  The following works to extract certain objects, but it's one of the ugliest things I've written.

Is there some javascript dark magic to do this elegantly?

```
function getEighthInsertionBlocks() {
    var struct = Lifestyle.Pagination.structure;
    var blocks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<struct.length; i++) {
        var page = struct[i];
        var layers = page.children;
        for (var j=0; j<layers.length; j++) {
            var layer = layers[j];
            if (layer.className === 'EighthPageLayer' ) {
                var rows = layer.children;
                for (var k=0; k<rows.length; k++) {
                    var row = rows[k];
                    eBlocks = row.children;
                    for (var l=0; l<eBlocks.length; l++) {
                        blocks.push(eBlocks[l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return blocks;
}
```

Not that I'm a big fan of code golf, but ... this is horrible.

Comment: You're exactly on par.

Comment: Just a thought, it might be more managable to use a foreach loop instead

Comment: Extract each loop into a method?

Comment: Deep structures need to be iterated deeply ; ). Whatever else way you'd write this, it would be slower, though you could move all the variable declarations to the top of the function.

Comment: You could use `map` and `filter` to get rid of the ugly loops and intermediate variables. It would probably be slower though.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a generic iterator, which would reduce the code into sequential blocks:

```
var iterator = function(collection, callback){
    var length = collection.length;
    var results = [];
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
        result = callback(colleciton[i], i);
        if (result){
            results = results.concat(result);
        }
    }
    return results;
};

function getEighthInsertionBlocks() {
    var struct = Lifestyle.Pagination.structure;
    var layers = iterator(struct, function(page){ return page.children; });
    var rows = iterator(layers, function(layer){
        return layer.className === 'EighthPageLayer' ? layer.children : null;
    });
    return iterator(rows, function(eBlocks, index){ return eblocks[index]; });
}
```

Comment: so nice ! :) Better than mine !

Comment: For this to work we need to concatenate the results, instead of push them. Otherwise we are effectively implementing `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure I follow your logic.  This works without concat.  Also, `Array.prototype.map` does not have IE8 support (in case that's needed).

Comment: @Stephen What I mean is this essentially a map instead of a concat. The way it works now is setting `layers` equal to an array of arrays. This means when processing the rows we are only iterating over `layers.length` items and receiving arrays of children as items—thus not iterating over the children.

Answer (score 0):

I usually tend to like using `forEach` for the readability but this is subjective.

```
function isEighthPageLayer(layer){
    return layer.className === "EighthPageLayer"
}

function getEighthInsertionBlocks(struct) {
    var blocks = [];
    struct.forEach(function(page){
        page.layers
            .filter(isEighthPageLayer)
            .forEach( function(layer) {
                layer.children.forEach(function(row){
                    row.children.forEach(function(eBlocks){
                        blocks.push(eBlocks);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return blocks;
}
```

Comment: Of course, the goal is to extract some functions from filter, forEach. I think the best candidate are functions taking layer argument. I make a warning.

Comment: @farvilian you could extract the functions passed to `forEach` into variables, and this would be a very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting challenge.  To avoid deep nesting, you need a generic iterator that you can use recursively, yet there are a few special cases in your iteration.  So, I tried to create a generic iterator that you can pass an options object to in order to specify the special conditions.  Here's what I came up with.  Since I don't have a sample data set, this is untested, but hopefully you see the idea:

```
function iterateLevel(data, options, level, output) {
    console.log("level:" + level);
    console.log(data);
    var fn = options[level] && options[level].fn;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (!fn || (fn(data[i]) === true)) {
            if (level === options.endLevel) {
                output.push(data[i]);
            } else {
                iterateLevel(data[i].children, options, level + 1, output);
            }
        }
    }
}

var iterateOptions = {
    "1": {
        fn: function(arg) {return arg.className === 'EighthPageLayer'}
    },
    "endLevel": 3
}
var blocks = [];
iterateLevel(Lifestyle.Pagination.structure, iterateOptions, 0, blocks);
```

The idea is that the options object can have an optional filter function for each level and it tells you how many levels to go down.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aQs6h/